# Ecclipse: Adding Javadoc comments in Php module fails

Tags: java, php, eclipse

I am writing a Php module using Eclipse. If a function contains

```
global $user;
```

and the some assignment

```
$user = user_load('Administrator');
```

then if I add Javadoc Comments to a function below, using /** I dont see auto-generated 
    `@param $var`

declaration anymore.

The same comments for the function below are generated perfectly if I delete global $user from a function above.

Exmaple:

```
/**
 * First function
 * @param unknown $row
 */
public function FirstFunction($row) {
  global $user;  
  $user = user_load('Administrator');
 ...
}

/**
 *  Second function
 * 
 */
public function SecondFunction($row) {
  ....
}

 No more @param unknown $row is present.
```